# Telling JSON.parse to tread a certain key as a string ? Is it possible

Tags: javascript, json

Suppose I have a json string as such. In the following string "**Quiz**" is an invalid json and I would like it to be treated as a string.

```
{"Name":"Bar","MName":"","__Quiz__":"{"TaskId":"9a568a59-8d34-41e2-9c66-8fb4c534e0be","Quiz":"{\"Quiz\":\"{\\\"Status\\\":\\\"Foo\\\"}\",\"Result\":\"Success\"}","Name":"Bar","Test":"Completed"}","type":"__ActionQuiz__"}
```

Is there anyway for me to tell JSO.parse to treat "**Quiz**" as a string and not as a json string ?

Comment: `"Key3" : "{"Key1":"Key2"}"` is not valid json. You can try it [here](https://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: please add the complete string, as you got it, without styling.

Comment: @Let me add the complete string

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: @MistyD This still isn't valid JSON.  What are you generating JSON like this?  Why are you trying to embed JSON as a string inside JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't valid JSON.

If it were valid JSON, quote marks would be escaped with a backslash, `\"`.

This data is ambiguous.  You need to go back and fix whatever is generating it, using a proper JSON encoder.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes for the key

```js
const a = {
"Key1":"val1",
"Key2": "val2",
"Key3" : '{"Key1":"Key2"}'
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: I do not have option of adjusting the quotes. I am getting them from somewhere else. I just have a string right now

Comment: dude this is not even a valid string  "{"Key1":"Key2"}"

Comment: I understand but that was just an example. I wanted to know if there is a way for me to ignore a certain key

Comment: you can delete it if there is no use of it

Comment: @MistyD you can use the second parameter of `JSON.parse(text[, reviver])` to ignore a key while parsing. But, not sure if that is what you need here.